Cors error persists no matter what I try with server
I have done everything possible to make this cors error go away but still no help.
I have uploaded my controller, app.js file for express and the request.
controller:
const login = async(req, res)=>{
    const {username, password} = req.body

    if(!username || !password){
       return res.status(200).json({message:'inavlid credentials'})
    }
    const user = await User.findOne({username:username})

    if(!user){
       return res.status(200).json({success:false, message:`user with username:${username} not found`})
    }

    const passwordCorrect = await user.comparePasswords(password)
    if(!passwordCorrect){
      return res.status(200).json({success:false, message:`no user with provided credentials`})
   }
   
    const token = await user.createToken()
    let respy = {user:user.username, token:token}
    const task = await Task.findOne({createdBy:user.username}).select("boards.name boards._id")

    if(task){
      respy.data = task
    }

    return res.status(200).json(respy)

Route:
router.route('/register').post(register)
router.route('/login').post(login)

module.exports = router;

server index file:
app.set('trust proxy', 1)
app.use(rateLimit({
    windowMs: 15 * 60 * 1000,
    limit: 1000
}))
app.use(helmet())
app.use(xss())
app.options('*', (req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', ["https://ifastaskmanager.netlify.app"]);
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, content-type, Origin, X-Requested-With, Authorization, Accept');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true)
    next();
} )
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', ["https://ifastaskmanager.netlify.app"]);
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, content-type, Origin, X-Requested-With, Authorization, Accept');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true)
    next();
});
//my routes codes below the above

request:
    const postLogin = async () => {
        try {
            let { data} = await axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/api/login`, userPass, {withCredentials:true)
            settings(data.data)
            localStorage.setItem('taskId', data.data._id)
            localStorage.setItem('token', data.token)
            goto()
        }
        catch (err) {
            setLoading(false)
            setErrMsg(err.message)
        }
    }

I have used fetch API instead of axios and no change. Sometimes it works good and many times it throws cors Access-Control-Allow-Origin missing even though it's not. I've used the npm cors package and played with all its options still no change. I'm using aws lambda to host the server and my other server on aws works well. Thanks for you assistance!
this is the error I get:
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://***********.amazonaws.com/latest/api/login. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 502.

access-control-allow-credentials
    true
access-control-allow-headers
    Content-Type, content-type, Origin, X-Requested-With, Authorization, Accept
access-control-allow-methods
    GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE
access-control-allow-origin
    https://ifastaskmanager.netlify.app/
allow
    POST
content-length
    4
content-security-policy
    default-src 'self';base-uri 'self';font-src 'self' https: data:;form-action 'self';frame-ancestors 'self';img-src 'self' data:;object-src 'none';script-src 'self';script-src-attr 'none';style-src 'self' https: 'unsafe-inline';upgrade-insecure-requests
content-type
    text/html; charset=utf-8
cross-origin-opener-policy
    same-origin
cross-origin-resource-policy
    same-origin
date
    Wed, 14 Aug 2024 15:25:22 GMT
etag
    W/"4-Yf+Bwwqjx254r+pisuO9HfpJ6FQ"
origin-agent-cluster
    ?1
referrer-policy
    no-referrer
strict-transport-security
    max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains
via
    1.1 d1770bd6cae759a3354f4f22aec533c2.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amz-apigw-id
    cgTe9FRbDoEErdA=
x-amz-cf-id
    DFdo6zwXM7xJboMGM4lACNSNJPEvZAnsm1PJx3XHI_f-ufnCMKvroQ==
x-amz-cf-pop
    MAN51-P2
x-amzn-remapped-connection
    keep-alive
x-amzn-remapped-content-length
    4
x-amzn-remapped-date
    Wed, 14 Aug 2024 15:25:21 GMT
x-amzn-requestid
    2e20c793-5397-4cd4-9c19-e22869549c45
x-amzn-trace-id
    Root=1-66bccc5f-4df753ff130075aa6354fe4f;Parent=1c993f9add57a541;Sampled=0;lineage=4c7e705a:0
x-cache
    Miss from cloudfront
x-content-type-options
    nosniff
x-dns-prefetch-control
    off
x-download-options
    noopen
X-Firefox-Spdy
    h2
x-frame-options
    SAMEORIGIN
x-permitted-cross-domain-policies
    none
x-ratelimit-limit
    1000
x-ratelimit-remaining
    999
x-ratelimit-reset
    1723650022
x-xss-protection
    0

I checked everything in my code base, I ran it locally and every works fine. so I can't trace where the 502 error code's cause is. Again, it works sometimes but most times it doesn't. Should I use EC2 instead? I have almost zero knowledge of EC2.

Hi, It may be possible, not sure, that if this request https://***********.amazonaws.com works only in logged in mode, then you may need to pass the credentials as well in your fetch - withCredentials: true. At present the fetch is just a cross origin CORS request with no credentials  - withCredentials: false.

@WeDoTheBest4You, I just changed it and still no change. I created a function URL in my lambda function, configured cors and now the cors error I'm battling is origin does not match even though it does. I've updated my question to include the new error.

Hi, Please see to this case as it is also a 'sometimes' case, and they have addressed it amicably. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50990823/default-response-headers-aws-api-gateway-w-proxy-integration

So far, this is what I did that works.
I had this in my model file:


 userSchema.methods.createToken = function(){
   return JWT.sign({userId:this._id, username:this.username}, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {expiresIn:"20d"})
 }

 userSchema.methods.comparePasswords = async function(candidatePassword){
    let matches = await bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, this.password)
     return matches
}



I commented it out in my model file and moved it directly to my login controller in my question above.
then in my login controller, I put all my login in a try and catch block instead of depending on the async error package.
then I moved my app.use(express.json()) above all other configurations basically where I was still requiring packages.
Then I removed my cors config, used cors package with following settings:


app.use(cors({
      allowedHeaders: ["authorization", "Content-Type", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"],
      exposedHeaders: ["authorization", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"],
      origin: "https://ifastaskmanager.netlify.app",
      methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
      preflightContinue: true,
      credentials:true,
      maxAge:600
}))



Knowing that this error comes and goes sometimes(Though hasn't been consistent for this long(10hrs now no error)), I'll give this 1 day or 2 to verify the error is officially gone for good, try to recreate and find the source before marking this as an answer
Aug 25th 2024 test result:
Today, I may have found the issue but I'm also going to let this run for two days before I mark as answer: I found typo in my mongoose schema; the required attribute was spelt reuqire so I had: password:{
type:String,
reuqired:[true, 'User password must be entered']
}.
But this doesn't explain why it works on local server and crashes when deployed.  Before correcting the typo, bcrypt.compare() was marking await keyword as unecessary even though bcrypt.compare() returns a promise but after correcting the typo, bcrypt.compare accepts the await keyword without marking it as unecessary.
sep 7 20204 after weeks of test:
The Problem seem to be the typo in the authentication schema. Because I've not had that cors issue since I corrected the typo. I wasn't able to figure out why it worked locally and crashes when deployed but I can say the cors issue is solved so I'm marking this as answer.

I decided to revisit the app today before I mark this answer and I found the problem. It's bcrypt. It's either returning true even when the password is wrong or just doens't work at all. I've compared my usage of bcrypt with docs and other users' questions and I don't see anything wrong with my codes or maybe I need second set of eyes to check.

if this error persist you can go to your lambda function in AWS console
Configuration> Functional Url tab
you will have to setup your cors here to allow origin that access the lambda function

I tried this before but it didn't work.. it instead gave a origin does not match error even though the origins match in the error message. I though it wasn't aws but I wrong. It has to be AWS lambda as I have retested everything locally and it is fine. The problem is in my bcrypt.compare block.

i am wondering how would bcrypt.compare block give you cors error  but anywy if is resolved then thats fine. just one question https://ifastaskmanager.netlify.app is this your FE url??

Yes that's my frontend. Thanks a lot for your input.

An origin is not a full URL. The origin includes the scheme, host and port but not the path, query or fragment.
In the list of headers you shared it included:
access-control-allow-origin: https://ifastaskmanager.netlify.app/

But this can never be correct. It must be:
access-control-allow-origin: https://ifastaskmanager.netlify.app


Thanks for the observation. I’ve long corrected that but it wasn’t the issue.
